# Company calendar recommendations?

Tags: calendar

I'm looking for a company calendar solution, and maybe a company directory utility.

- We're a cross platform workplace (Windows, a couple of Linux variations, Mac). We need clients (or a quality web interface) available for each platform.
- External hosting (e.g. Google calendar), is not acceptable.
- Open to commercial solutions.
- A good quality web interface to our IMAP server would also be a plus.

Any recommendations?

Comment: SO tempted to reply with a link to the Pirelli one ;)

Comment: I'm really liking my guide dogs calendar this year... "awwww, labrador puppies!"

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you are willing to look into a complete collaboration suite.  But [Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com) has awesome calendaring and not to mention the great email web client/server.  They have an open source version(FOSS) which is great for most needs and a paid/supported version (Network).

Comment: Interesting. Looks nice - I especially like the ability to tag emails. Re: email. Some of our staff still use emacs and pine. How much would Zimbra prevent us from running our existing email systems in parallel (IMAP, SpamAssassin). Can you set up a Zimbra server that uses IMAP for storage?

Comment: Yes.  Zimbra will serve IMAP and POP3 clients.  But I would recommend using there web client as much as possible.  It sounds like you can migrate from your existing email setup to Zimbra with ease.  Zimbra uses SpamAssassin and ClamAV to scan the emails before they hit mailboxes.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem odd, but our University used to run MeetingMaker which ONLY does calendar-but it does it well and with simple hardware requirements. You can also purchase an add-on that will give you push calendar sync to smartphones. The pricing was not unreasonable for MeetingMaker.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint would have you covered, but I'm not sure you really want to go there if you don't have to :)

Comment: WSS has ok calendaring. It's even better if you're already working with Office 2007. Everything syncs up nicely between Outlook and WSS.

Comment: he said "quality" web interface... :)

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird has a [Lightning](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/lightning/) extension that gives you calendaring. [Mozilla's calendar project](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/) also has [Sunbird](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/sunbird/) which is an independent calendaring solution.

Lightning can also communicate with Exchange calendars via Davmail, or any iCal-based calendar server.

Runs on Linux, Windows and Mac (plus others)